# How do I promote a board game to the masses?

Tags: game-design, game-development, prototyping

I created a board game for playing while watching American Football with your friends. We always had a great time playing it and anybody outside of our group who saw it immediately loved it. So I thought it's a no brainer, it's time to sell this.

The name of the game is Big Bucks Football. And I built my website and twitter and Facebook and YouTube, and I believe I have about 8 hits. I am active, I tweet on twitter, I share on Facebook, I have instructional videos on YouTube, but still no success.

My question is, has anyone here had any success, or have any ideas on how to promote the game? I have a limited budget but I'm willing to put the time in. I just started my Kickstarter campaign, but I'm already worried if that doesn't work I may start pulling my hair out cause I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I think in this form your question comes across as spammy. Maybe it would be better to remove the links and focus on the question, rather than trying to use the question to promote your game.

Comment: @Jefromi Fair, enough, I was trying to show I put the work in which is why I downplayed the links - either way, the links are removed.

Comment: @Jefromi also thought if an answer was going to be provided people may want to take a look at the material and see where I could improve. Come to think of it, I'm wondering how you could provide an accurate answer without the links?

Comment: I think simply describing what you've done is plenty. Asking people to look over all your content is probably too broad (and maybe even off topic). And besides, it's better not to ask a question that's limited to your own specific case; you can instead ask a generic question that'll be useful to future readers.

Comment: You are asking the community to help you put together a marketing campaign for a board game. I think that is off topic here. I don't see a Stack Exchange for marketing, but if there was one, I imagine that "How can I market this?" would be too broad in the same sense that "How can I program this?" is too broad for Stack Overflow. You should consider investing in the [Digital Marketing proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65811/digital-marketing) over on Area 51.

Comment: @Rainbolt probably a good idea, this is becoming counter-productive.

Comment: @JohnnyUX, this would be on topic if it's specifically about what it takes to market a boardgame, separately from marketing other products.  I have some experience with that, which I'd be happy to share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting a board game (design, prototype, print&play or kickstarter) should definitely involve BoardGameGeek, and similar communities.

I could expand, but everything's covered in this article: http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/322382/game-design-self-publishing-resource-game-designer

You should provide print&play materials for playtesting groups, to see if most people actually agree on your game's quality. And the feedback can lead to an improved game.
If your game **is** better than good, the word will spread (forum threads growing longer, enthusiastic playtesters recommending it to their neighbours' moms, etc.)

And: the "masses" (as in: everybody not actively following the boardgaming industry) will only encounter a game once it's physically for sale in shops. That's why every family with two kids has a copy of Monopoly but not Agricola, Diplomacy or Twilight Struggle.

Comment: Thanks Frederik. The game is listed on boardgamegeek. I'll look into the play testing groups and similar communities.